# How to display an image as your whole webpage?

Tags: image, html

I did give a search before I started to ask this question as it is a very simple question. I have an image and I would like to have it as the only element on our webpage. There is no other content as this image conveys what we want to convey. Now we would also like to resize itself depending upon the device it is being displayed. I hope this is achievable through HTML though I would like to know if there is any other options.

Thank you,

Karsnen

Comment: You need more markup than just an image - using CSS as well...

Comment: "resize" - to completely fill the browser window? Or a certain min/max size? Or a percentage of the browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an image as a web resource (“page”). You could simply link to it using something like `href="test.jpg"`, or you could announce its URL directly. Browsers will display it somehow, possibly scaling it to fit browser window width.

The next simpler, and better, approach is to use a page with just an `img` element as its content. It can be made to scale to browser window width by setting its width to 100% (in HTML or in CSS). This way, it will keep its width:height proportion when scaled. The quality of scaling in browsers varies but is generally good, unless you scale upwards a lot. In this approach, the inherent width of the image should be sufficiently large (say 2,000 pixels) to avoid considerable upwards scaling.

To remove default spacing around the image (default page margins), it’s simplest to use CSS.

Example (with “...” to be replaced by useful information):

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>...</title>
<style>
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
<img src="demo.jpg" alt="..." width="100%">
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `background-size` property. By applying `background-size:cover`  to your `<body>`, the image will resize itself accordingly regardless of viewport dimensions. 
*Note: Your image may clip with the use of **cover**.*

An alternative value for `background-size` can also be **contain**. If you apply `background-size:contain` instead, it'll still resize the image accordingly just as the former would. 
*Note: While this approach promises to never clip the image, it'll also show negative/dead space as well (which sometimes isn't ideal).*

Your CSS should reflect the following:

```
body {
 background-image: url('bg.jpg');
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover; /* or background-size: contain */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it as a `background-image` and use the appropriate `background-size` (e.g. `contain`):

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: url('to/your/image.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/EgCds/)

Answer (score -1):

I use this: 
css

```
#body{
    background:url(../img/bg.jpg);
    margin: 0;
}
```

javascript

```
$("#body").css('width',window.innerWidth)
$("#body").css('height',window.innerHeight)
```

Comment: That won't react to browser resizing, won't change the size of the image, won't play well with margins, and is not a very efficient way to go about this.

Comment: sorry, I thought he wanted background on the entire page as an image in any size, my mistake